# Enthought Traits.HasTraits class as a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, enthought, traits, traitsui

Imagine I have the following Traits objects:

```
from traits.api import Int, HasTraits, Instance

class Foo(HasTraits):
    a = Int(2)
    b = Int(5)

class Bar(HasTraits):
    c = Int(7)
    foo = Instance(Foo,())
```

`Bar` will let me access attribute `a` on `Foo` via:

```
bar = Bar()
bar.foo.a
>>> 2
```

Is there a standard way to return `bar` as a nested dictionary of the form:

```
print bar_as_dict 
>>> {'c':7, 'foo':{'a':2, 'b':5}}
```

I'm essentially trying to extract all subtraits on an object that are a particular type.  Our use case is we have deeply-nested HasTrait objects that have plot traits, and we are trying to dynamically find all the plots on a particular object.  We have a function that can return the plots from a nested dictionary, but we need to pass HasTrait objects in, so formatting them into nested dictionaries would be great.  If there is another way to dynamically inspect the stack of a HasTraits object and return all traits of a certain type, that would work too.

[Here's a link to the HasTraits API](http://code.enthought.com/projects/files/ETS3_API/enthought.traits.has_traits.HasTraits.html#trait_names)... couldn't figure this out directly from that.

### Solution Attempt

I've tried using the `.traits()` method, but it returns these `CTrait` objects.

```
print bar.traits()
>>>{'trait_added': <traits.traits.CTrait object at 0x8b7439c>,
 'c': <traits.traits.CTrait object at 0x8b29e9c>, 
'foo': <traits.traits.CTrait object at 0x8b29e44>, 
'trait_modified': <traits.traits.CTrait object at 0x8b74344>}
```

Which don't evaluate as I'd expect:

```
isinstance(bar.traits()['c'], int)
>>> False
```

But after Pieter's suggestion, this works:

```
print bar.traits()['c'].is_trait_type(Int)
>>> True
```

Now the question is how to do this recursively.

Comment: I figure the TreeEditor does this at some point since it lets you dynamically inspect these objects.  I'll keep looking through the editor source codes to try to poinpoint this behavior as well.

Comment: `bar.traits()['c']` is a `CTrait`, so it's obviously not an `int`. But according to the documentation, `CTrait`s have a method named `is_trait_type`. Have you tried calling that? I guess it'll require `Int` as argument, not `int`, given that it takes a trait_type.

Comment: Thanks, that works and gets me closer.  Now I have to try to modify that recursion code I have to do this on a nested object.  I'l update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after [following a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131446/get-nested-arrays-out-of-a-dictionary) on recursion of a nested dictionary **without** Trait values

```
def flatten_traitobject(traitobject, *types):
    node_map = {}
    node_path = [] 
    def nodeRecursiveMap(traitobject, node_path): 
        for key in traitobject.editable_traits():
            val = traitobject.get(key)[key]
            for type in types:
                if isinstance(val, types[0]):
                    node_map['.'.join(node_path + [key])] = val 
            try:
                nodeRecursiveMap(val, node_path + [key])
            except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                pass
    nodeRecursiveMap(traitobject, node_path)
    return node_map
```

Testing it out, I can choose to retain only integers and/or only objects of type `Foo`

```
bar=Bar()
print 'RETAINING ONLY INTEGER TYPES'
print flatten_traitobject(bar, int)
print '\nRETAINTING ONLY FOO OBJECT TYPES'
print flatten_traitobject(bar, Foo)

>>> RETAINING ONLY INTEGER TYPES
>>> {'c': 7, 'foo.b': 5, 'foo.a': 2}

>>> RETAINTING ONLY FOO OBJECT TYPES
>>> {'foo': <__main__.Foo object at 0x8f9308c>}
```

Foo represents the special plotting traits I'm after, so I can effectively return them now.

Comment: Note: This will end up with recursion errors if any references from child to parent exist.  For example, if a nested object references back to its parent.