# How to find repeats or duplicates in nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary and I'm trying to find duplicates within in. For example, if I have:

```
dictionary = {'hello': 3 , 'world':{'this': 5 , 'is':{'a': 3, 'dict': None}}}
```

The return value would be something like:

```
True
```

because this dictionary contains duplicates.

I was able to do this quite easily with a regular dictionary, and I thought this would work well with this case too:

```
dictionary = {'hello': 3 , 'world':{'this': 5 , 'is':{'a': 3, 'dict': None}}}
rev_dictionary = {}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    rev_dictionary.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
    print(rev_dictionary)

for key,values in dictionary.items():
    if len(values) > 1:
        values = True
    else:
        values = False
```

which throws the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I get this working?

Thanks for the help!

**Note:** I'd prefer a solution without using libraries if possible

Comment: Define _"duplicates."_ In my opionion, even if I am given `{"1": {"CPU": "AMD", "OS": "Linux", "Hostname": "spicy-tequila"}, "2": {"CPU": "AMD", "OS": "Linux", "Hostname": "coy-wolves"}}`, these are still two distinct objects, regardless of the fact that they share some commonalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are defining duplicates by value and not by keys. In that case, you can flatten the nested dict using ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081545/python-3-flattening-nested-dictionaries-and-lists-within-dictionaries))

```
def flatten(d):
    out = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            val = [val]
        if isinstance(val, list):
            for subdict in val:
                deeper = flatten(subdict).items()
                out.update({key + '_' + key2: val2 for key2, val2 in deeper})
        else:
            out[key] = val
    return out
```

and then check for the condition

```
v = flatten(d).values()
len(set(v))!=len(v)
```

results in  True

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple solution:

```
dictionary = {'hello': 3 , 'world':{'this': 5 , 'is':{'a': 3, 'dict': None}}}

def get_dups(a, values=None):
    if values is None: values = []
    if (a in values): return True
    values.append(a)
    if type(a) == dict:
        for i in a.values():
            if (get_dups(i, values=values)):
                return True
    return False

print(get_dups(dictionary))
```

### How it works

We start by saving every `value` in a list, which we will pass into the function.
Each run we check whether our current value is in that list, and return `True` once there is a duplicate.

```
if (a in values): return True
```

Next we just loop through the values and run `get_dups` on them if the current index is also a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to flatten the dict before passing to your duplication-detection pipeline:

```
import pandas as pd

def flatten_dict(d):
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d, sep='_')
    return df.to_dict(orient='records')[0]

dictionary = {'hello': 3 , 'world':{'this': 5 , 'is':{'a': 3, 'dict': None}}}

dictionary = flatten_dict(dictionary)
print('flattend')
print(dictionary)

rev_dictionary = {}

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    rev_dictionary.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)

print('reversed')
print(rev_dictionary)

is_duplicate = False
for key, values in rev_dictionary.items():
    if len(values) > 1:
        is_duplicate = True
        break

print('is duplicate?', is_duplicate)
```

The result:

```
flattend
{'hello': 3, 'world_is_a': 3, 'world_is_dict': None, 'world_this': 5}
reversed
{3: {'hello', 'world_is_a'}, None: {'world_is_dict'}, 5: {'world_this'}}
is duplicate? True
```

Code for flattening a dict borrowed from: [Flatten nested Python dictionaries, compressing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027558/flatten-nested-python-dictionaries-compressing-keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively add item values of sub-dicts to a set, and if any item value is already "seen" in the set, raise an exception so that the wrapper can return `True` to indicate that a dupe is found:

```
def has_dupes(d):
    def values(d):
        seen = set()
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                s = values(v)
                if seen & s:
                    raise RuntimeError()
                seen.update(s)
            else:
                if v in seen:
                    raise RuntimeError()
                seen.add(v)
        return seen
    try:
        values(d)
    except RuntimeError:
        return True
    return False
```

so that given your sample input, `has_dupes(dictionary)` would return: `True`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the nested dictionary into nested lists of their values:

```
def nested_values(v):
    return map(nested_values, v.values()) if isinstance(v, dict) else v
```

Then flatten the nested lists into one list of all values in the dictionaries,
and then check the flattened list of values for duplicates:

```
from itertools import chain

def is_duplicated_value(d):
    flat = list(chain.from_iterable(nested_values(d)))
    return len(flat) != len(set(flat))
```

Test:

```
print is_duplicated_value( {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:{1:'c', 2:'a'}} )
print is_duplicated_value( {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:{1:'c', 2:'d'}} )
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
```

Depending on your use and size of dictionaries etc you may want to recast these steps into a recursive function that adds each value to a `set` checking if each value is in the set before adding and returning `True` immediately or `False` if the dictionary is exhausted.

```
class Duplicated(ValueError): pass

def is_dup(d):
    values = set()
    def add(v):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            map(add, v.values())
        else:
            if v in values:
                raise Duplicated
            else:
                values.add(v)
    try:
        add(d)
        return False
    except Duplicated:
        return True
```

Test:

```
print is_dup( {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:{1:'c', 2:'a'}} )
print is_dup( {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:{1:'c', 2:'d'}} )
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
```