# Convert list values which contain integers and strings to string after flattening a dictionary

Tags: python, function, type-conversion, flatten

I want to convert list values that contain integers and strings to string after flattening. List that contains dictionary should be flattened

Dictionary I have:

```
{
    "main_key": [
        {
            "key1": "val1",
            "key2": 0,
            "key3": [2,72,140],
            "key4": ["val2","val3","val4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55834113/20721664) helped me very well, but it doesn't convert list value to string.
I am using this code:

```
def flatten(input_dict, separator='/', prefix=''):
    output_dict = {}
    for key, value in input_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict) and value:
            deeper = flatten(value, separator, prefix+key+separator)
            output_dict.update({key2: val2 for key2, val2 in deeper.items()})
        elif isinstance(value, list) and value:
            for sublist in value:
                if isinstance(sublist, dict) and sublist:
                    deeper = flatten(sublist, separator, prefix+key+separator)
                    output_dict.update({key2: val2 for key2, val2 in deeper.items()})
                elif isinstance(sublist, list):
                    output_dict[sublist] = ', '.join([str(ele) for ele in input_dict[sublist]])
                else:
                    output_dict[prefix+key] = value
        else:
            output_dict[prefix+key] = value
    return output_dict
```

I get:

```
{'main_key/key1': 'val1',
 'main_key/key2': 0,
 'main_key/key3': [2, 72, 140],
 'main_key/key4': ['val2', 'val3', 'val4']}
```

I expect:

```
{'main_key/key1': 'val1',
 'main_key/key2': 0,
 'main_key/key3': '2, 72, 140',
 'main_key/key4': 'val2, val3, val4'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because inside the `if isinstance(value, list)` block, you check the type of each element of `value` and if those elements are not a list or dict, you do:

```
output_dict[prefix+key] = value
```

This sets the output dict to `value`, which is a list.

As a hacky fix, do

```
output_dict[prefix+key] = ", ".join(str(v) for v in value)
```

Ideally you should be doing this *outside* the `for sublist in value` loop. I suspect you don't need that loop anyway and can instead just check the type of the first element (if you assume that all elements of a list have the same type)